# What does this "too to" mean here?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, negation

**They are too imaginary not to be false.**

What does this mean?
It is so complicated.

My theory is "too imaginary to be real."

Comment: Can you give some additional context?  It's hard to tell exactly what is meant by *imaginary* with this sentence alone.

Comment: Thank you. I should have add this . "These characters in this play are too imaginary not to be false. "

Comment: I think you got it right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OP seems to have answered the question by commenting that he means *too imaginary not to be false* (where ***too*** means *excessively*, and ***to*** is just part of the infinitive verb form in *to be*). Probably the most common form of this construction is [too good to be true](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22too%20good%20to%20be%20true%22&oq=%22too%20good%20to%20be%20true%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.6869j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) (Google claims over 10 million instances there).

But it's worth noting that native speakers wouldn't normally describe characters in plays (or theories) as *too imaginary*. Far more likely is:-

> *They are [too far-fetched](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22too%20far-fetched%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) [to be true, credible, believable, etc.]*

---

> [**far-fetched**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/far-fetched) - very unlikely to be true, and difficult to believe.

Answer (score 3):

***Z** is too **X** to be **Y*** is a fairly standard format, meaning that the qualities X and Y at some point become exclusive, and item Z has passed that point; it has so much X that it can no longer be Y.  You can rephrase this as *So X that it can't be Y*.

Conversely,  *too **X** NOT to be **Y*** means that X and Y are linked traits; whenever you have enough X, you always have Y as well.  You can rephrase this as *So X that it MUST be Y*.

Thus, if the sentence under question is "The characters in this play are too imaginary not to be false", then they are so imaginary that they must be false.